# Problem displaying a button using Popup screen

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a App that use a Popup screen, but on my phone and not show all the way , I guess it has to do with phone resolution, Because on the emulator at show all the way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKx31.jpg)

As you see on the image I cant see the button

And also ,can i force the phone to open at default resolution ?

This is the emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Opf.jpg)

This is my code that call the PopUp window

```
        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final DialogPlus dialogPlus = DialogPlus.newDialog(holder.Time.getContext())
                    .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.update_popup))
                    .setExpanded(true, 1200)
                    .create();
            //dialogPlus.show();
            View view = dialogPlus.getHolderView();
            //EditText Time = view.findViewById(R.id.txttime);
            EditText Airplanename = view.findViewById(R.id.txtairplane);
            EditText Description = view.findViewById(R.id.txtdescription);
            EditText Partnum = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpartnumber);
            EditText Status = view.findViewById(R.id.txtdeliverstatus);
```

note:
the phone i use it galaxy note 5g ultra
and the emulator i use it Pixel 2 Api 32

best regards to all

I try to fix the Popup screen that will show all the object

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: I got it , I chance the .setExpanded(true, 1200) to .setExpanded(true, 1800)

But how I can set a  default resolution ,because on difference phone has difference resolution .

Comment: I use firebase as my database

Answer (score 0):

To be specific, I don't know what dimension setExpanded 1200 horizontal or vertical refers to, but to get the X-Y dimension of a device you can do this

```java
     DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
     int xWidth = (int)(0.25 * metrics.xdpi);
     int yHeight = (int)(0.25 * metrics.ydpi);

 final DialogPlus dialogPlus = DialogPlus.newDialog(holder.Time.getContext())
            .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.update_popup))
            .setExpanded(true, yHeight)
            .create();
```

Comment: setExpanded 1200 that for how far the window will come from the bottom screen